# Как конвертировать ZipEntry в byte[]?

Tags: java

Есть объект типа `ZipEntry`, который является `txt` файлом. Каким образом я могу получить его содержание в `byte[]` виде?

Пробовал `IOUtils.toByteArray(ZipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry))`, но выдает ошибку `non-static method getInputStream(ZipEntry) cannot be referenced from a static context`

Возможно ли исправить ошибку? Или есть другой способ перевода данный в массив байтов?

Comment: `getInputStream` - не статический метод. Вы вызываете его от класса, вызывайте от объекта `ZipFile`.

Comment: но что тогда передавать в качестве параметра при создании объекта ZipFile

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html